# Wrong date format for input parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(
   V_STARTTIME    IN DATE,
   V_ENDTIME      IN DATE)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TAB1
SELECT COINS FROM TAB2
WHERE DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(V_STARTTIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(V_ENDTIME,'MM/DD/YYYY');
COMMIT;
END;
```

`SAMPLE DATE in Tab2 IS TIMESTAMP DATATYPE 5/5/2014 9:46:38.000000 AM`

When I try to execute

`Execute PROC1(TO_DATE('5/5/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('5/6/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'));`

the procedure is successfully completed but my Insert into was ignored.

I tried printing the input date through `dbms_output.put_line` and the date did not return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very, very similar to the [question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524431/not-a-valid-month-when-executing-an-in-parameter-procedure-with-date-value).

If `v_starttime` and `v_endtime` are of type `date`, it makes no sense to call `to_date` on them.  `to_date` does not take an argument of type `date`.  It takes a parameter of type `varchar2`.  If you try to pass a `date` to `to_date`, Oracle has to implicitly cast the `date` to a `varchar2` using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  If that doesn't match the format mask you're passing to `to_date`, you may get an error or you may get an incorrect result.  As in yesterday's question, you want to avoid implicit conversions.

A `date` in Oracle has both a day and a time component (to the second).  If you are doing the `to_date` in order to ensure that the time component is midnight, use the `trunc` function instead.

```
INSERT INTO TAB1( column_name )
  SELECT COINS 
    FROM TAB2
   WHERE <<timestamp column>> BETWEEN trunc( v_starttime ) AND trunc( v_endtime );
```

You say that your "insert was ignored".  That seems highly unlikely.  It's much more likely that your `SELECT` statement returned 0 rows so your `INSERT` inserted 0 rows.  That's not an error.  If you want to treat it as an error, you'd need to check `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after the `INSERT` and throw an error if the `INSERT` statement inserts 0 rows.

If the `SELECT` was not selecting any rows because of an implicit conversion error, then getting rid of the `to_date` and potentially adding the `trunc` would fix the problem.

Comment: @JohnD - following up on Justin's suggestion, you could add the following line of code: `IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;` after the INSERT statement in your procedure if you wanted an exception to be raised in the case where no data was inserted into the target table. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

The function [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) requires string as first parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(
   V_STARTTIME    IN DATE,
   V_ENDTIME      IN DATE)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TAB1
   SELECT COINS FROM TAB2 WHERE DATE BETWEEN V_STARTTIME AND V_ENDTIME;
 COMMIT; --You should not use commit in procedure.
END;
```